# How did the pilot survive the crash?

Tags: lateral-thinking

One sunny day, as he usually does, the pilot was flying his plane. All of a sudden, a wing fell off and the plane started spiralling towards the ground. The pilot didn't eject nor bail out. The plane smashed into the ground with great force and disintegrated into a thousand pieces.

However, the pilot walked away unscathed. How is this possible?

Note: All of this happened in the real world.

Comment: Perhaps he was just very lucky; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sole_survivors_of_airline_accidents_or_incidents

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is because:

> His plane was just a toy, a model, so he wasn't in the plane when it crashed.

Comment: It wasn't that difficult, was it?

Comment: I get it with the title alone :) But that's a nice beginning!

Comment: Perhaps _robotics_ is the applicable tag to this puzzle, based on the accepted correct answer.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay wouldn't that be a spoiler?

Comment: @Erbureth no, definitely not, assuming by the context you had in your mind...A walking pilot toy out of a crashed toy plane...is unimaginable for me without the help of *robotics*

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Questions are judged based on the question, never on the answer.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay That can totally be a paper plane :) (with 1 sheet of paper per wing)

Answer (score 12):

> His plane was a military drone, so he wasn't in the plane when it crashed.

Answer (score 6):

He was flying his plane

> in a [computer simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Plane_(simulator)). He walked away unscathed from his PC, because he lost the game.

Comment: The question specifies "in the real world", so not in a simulator.

Comment: @Chromatix I interpreted it as "it's not fictional, happened to me or someone I know", i.e. the computer game has been really played in the real world, the pilot really walked away from his PC etc...

Answer (score 4):

> 'twas a remote control airplane.

Comment: @JulianCuenfuegos Welcome to PSE. Answers without any reasoning tend to get down-votes.

Answer (score 3):

All of a sudden, a wing fell off and the plane started spiralling towards the ground.

---

> It was a wing of another plane and another plane has crashed. The pilot just landed normally and walked away. There is no mention it all happened to the pilot's plane.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the answer is:

> The wing fell off of another plane. And pilot was in his plane.

As mentioned in the question

```
One sunny day, as he usually does, the pilot was flying his plane.
```

Comment: Don't forget to use ">!" to hide your answers! Also it seems that your answer is really close to Máté Juhász's answer, isn't it?